# incremental backup in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, backup

I am using this function for getting **full backup** of my mysql db.

```
function backup()
        {   


            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
            $date  = date("d-m-Y, g:i A");

            $folder = "application/backup";

            $prefs = array(
                    'tables'      => array('table1', 'table2')
                                 );


            $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

            write_file("application/backup/backup $date.sql.gz", $backup);


        }
```

But I need to get the **Incremental backup** of my mysql database hourly in codeigniter. What are the changes required to this code for getting the **incremental backup**?.

Comment: if you want to take entire table you can use cron job to get the whole table backup. Otherwise create custom function and keep track of the auto increment column number in local storage/database and get the results and keep the backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter Database Utillity Class doesn't allow you to make a Incremental backup of the database. If you need that you should create a custom library for that. Library should be able to run sql commands. Please read for details about Incremental backup in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html

Answer (score 0):

here, maybe you need to try this one.

```
ob_start();

// Generage HTML page here
generate_full_html_page();

// All magic goes here
$output = ob_get_clean();
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output));
header("Content-Encoding: none");
echo $output.str_repeat(' ', 10000) ."\n\n\n";
flush();

// Now page is sent and it safe to do all needed stuff here
cron_task1();
cron_task2();
```

i read this interesting technique from http://a32.me/2012/01/do-php-cron-without-cron-available/. may be you can modify your code base on that tutorial.

hopefully help you.